# Copy and move a file but DO NOT delete original using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking for a solution using node.js that will copy, move, and rename a file from one directory to another without deleting the original. Other solutions I've found seem to delete the original such as `fs.rename`.

This will run in a repo using npm.

Comment: *"that will copy, move, and rename a file from one directory to another without deleting the original"* That's just copying.

Comment: What in your definition is the difference between "copy, move, and rename" and just doing a copy to a new location with a new name?
I.e. why is `fs.copyFile("some/location/someName", "some/otherLocation/someOtherName")` not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Standard [node:fs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/fs.html) module is pretty enough for all of your purposes.
In particular you can achieve your goals with a help of [fs.copyFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/fs.html#fscopyfilesrc-dest-mode-callback)